# What visa options does a Jordanian citizen have for staying in Georgia (the country) for longer than 30 days?

Tags: visas, georgia-country

Unlike myself who can stay in Georgia for 360 days visa-free as a tourist, my friend travelling with a Jordanian passport is only given 30 days on a full-page visa in her passport.

Possibly, if she wants to stay longer she can do a visa run once per month and use up a page of her passport each time. But is there another option available to her?

The Georgian Ministry of Foreign Affairs page, **["Visa Information for Foreign Citizens"](http://www.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=96)**, is a bit ambiguous or at least not 100% clear. There is a heading, **"Visa fees (except for citizens of the Russian Federation)"** which says:

> Multiple ordinary VISAs for 360 days-50 $

What's not clear is, does this apply to everybody from every country? Can my Jordanian friend get a visa equivalent to mine just buy paying this $50 fee?

It's not clear because this friend and another on a Kuwaiti passport think they paid more than this same section states for their current 30-day visas. (They're not positive though since it was a couple of weeks ago and various currencies were involved.)

Also does this mean she has to apply from outside Georgia? I believe she has residency in Turkey so she could go back there when her 30 day visa expires and apply for one of these 360 day visas. If she can upgrade here it would be better, if she had to apply from Jordan it would not work out at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My Jordanian friend just got back from visiting the immigration office here in Tbilisi with a Georgian friend.

It seems she couldn't get the 360-day visa.

She could get a 90-day visa.

The price was still $50 but there was also $20 in other fees for I think translation and photo.

Answer (score 3):

According to the same site as well as the [CRA](http://www.cra.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=44&info_id=1511):

> Foreign citizen, who has entered the country legally, may apply in any
>   territorial office of the Civil Registry Agency and in case of
>   producing all necessary documents receive Ordinary VISA of Georgia.
>   Two types of ordinary VISA are issued by the territorial offices of
>   the Agency:
>
> 1. multiple ordinary VISA valid for 360 days;
> 2. Single ordinary VISA valid trough 90 days.

So you would need to find an office of the CRA and check with them what is needed to extend her visa.

Comment: Here is a list of CRA offices in Tbilisi: http://www.cra.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=23